# Modify code to auto complete on taxonomies instead of title

Tags: autocomplete, wordpress, taxonomy

I've been trying for hours to modify this plugin to work with custom taxonomies instead of post titles and/or post content

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kau-boys-autocompleter/

Added the code / part of the plugin where I think the modification should be done. I could post some stuff I tried but I think it would just confuse people, I don't think I ever came close. Normally I can modify code perfectly but just can't seem to find it. I've tried this method posted here.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/autocomplete-taxonomy-in-stead-of-title-or-content

But it doesn't work. I've tried searching for possible solutions around his suggestion but I'm starting to think his suggestion isn't even close to fixing it.

```
if(WP_DEBUG){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    } else {
        error_reporting(0);     
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// remove the filter functions from relevanssi
if(function_exists('relevanssi_kill')) remove_filter('posts_where', 'relevanssi_kill');
if(function_exists('relevanssi_query')) remove_filter('the_posts', 'relevanssi_query');
if(function_exists('relevanssi_kill')) remove_filter('post_limits', 'relevanssi_getLimit');

$choices = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_choices');
$framework = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_framework');
$encoding = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_encoding');
$searchfields = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_searchfields');
$resultfields = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_resultfields');
$titlelength = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_titlelength');
$contentlength = get_option('kau-boys_autocompleter_contentlength');
if(empty($choices)) $choices = 10;
if(empty($framework)) $framework = 'jQuery';
if(empty($encoding)) $encoding = 'UTF-8';
if(empty($searchfields)) $searchfields = 'both';
if(empty($resultfields)) $resultfields = 'both';
if(empty($titlelength)) $titlelength = 50;
if(empty($contentlength)) $contentlength = 120;

mb_internal_encoding($encoding);
mb_regex_encoding($encoding);

$words = '%'.$_REQUEST['q'].'%';

switch($searchfields){
    case 'post_title' : 
        $where = 'post_title LIKE "'.$words.'"';
        break;
    case 'post_content' : 
        $where = 'post_content LIKE "'.$words.'"';
    default :
        $where = 'post_title LIKE "'.$words.'" OR post_content LIKE "'.$words.'"';
}

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array(
    's' => $_REQUEST['q'],
    'showposts' => $choices,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

 $posts = $wp_query->posts;

$results = array();
foreach ($posts as $key => $post){
     setup_postdata($post);
     $title = strip_tags(html_entity_decode(get_the_title($post->ID), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'));


    $content = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(html_entity_decode(get_the_content($post->ID), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
    if(mb_strpos(mb_strtolower(($searchfields == 'post_title')? $title : (($searchfields == 'post_content')? $content : $title.$content)), mb_strtolower($_REQUEST['q'])) !== false){
        $results[] = array(
            'url' => get_permalink($post->ID),
            'title' => highlightSearchString(strtruncate($title, $titlelength, true), $_REQUEST['q']),
            'content' => (($resultfields == 'both')? highlightSearchString(strtruncate($content, $contentlength, false, '[...]', $_REQUEST['q']), $_REQUEST['q']) : '')
        );
    }
}
printResults($results, $framework);


function highlightSearchString($value, $searchString){

    if((version_compare(phpversion(), '5.0') < 0) && (strtolower(mb_internal_encoding()) == 'utf-8')){
        $value = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(utf8_decode($value)));
    }

    $regex_chars = '\.+?(){}[]^$';
    for ($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($regex_chars); $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($regex_chars, $i, 1);
        $searchString = str_replace($char, '\\'.$char, $searchString);
    }
    $searchString = '(.*)('.$searchString.')(.*)';
    return mb_eregi_replace($searchString, '\1<span class="ac_match">\2</span>\3', $value);
}

function strtruncate($str, $length = 50, $cutWord = false, $suffix = '...', $needle = ''){

    $str = trim($str);
    if((version_compare(phpversion(), '5.0') < 0) && (strtolower(mb_internal_encoding()) == 'utf-8')){
        $str = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode(utf8_decode($str)));
    }else{
        $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, mb_internal_encoding());
    }


    if(mb_strlen($str)>$length){
        if(!empty($needle) && mb_strpos(mb_strtolower($str), mb_strtolower($needle)) > 0){
            $pos = mb_strpos(mb_strtolower($str), mb_strtolower($needle)) + (mb_strlen($needle) / 2);
            $startToShort = ($pos - ($length / 2)) < 0;
            $endToShort = ($pos + ($length / 2)) > mb_strlen($str);

            // build the prefix and suffix
            $prefix = $suffix;
            if($startToShort){
                $prefix = '';
            }
            if($endToShort){
                $suffix = '';
            }

            // set maximum length
            $length = $length - mb_strlen($prefix) - mb_strlen($suffix);

            // get the start
            if($startToShort){
                $start = 0;
            } elseif($endToShort){
                $start = mb_strlen($str) - $length;
            } else {
                $start = $pos - ($length / 2);
            }


            // shorten the string
            $string = mb_substr($str, $start, $length);

            if($cutWord){
                return $prefix.$string.$suffix;
            } else {
                $firstWhitespace = ($startToShort)? 0 : mb_strpos($string, ' ');
                $lastWhitespace =($endToShort)? mb_strlen($string) :  mb_strrpos($string, ' ');
                return $prefix.' '.(!empty($lastWhitespace)? mb_substr($string, $firstWhitespace, ($lastWhitespace - $firstWhitespace)) : $string).' '.$suffix;
            }
        } else {
            $string = mb_substr($str, 0, $length - mb_strlen($suffix));
            return (($cutWord) ? $string : mb_substr($string, 0, mb_strrpos($string, ' ')).' ').$suffix;
        }
    } else {
        return $str;    
    }
}

function printResults($results, $framework){
    if($framework == 'scriptaculous'){          
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo '  <li>
                        <a href="'.$result['url'].'">
                            <span class="title">'.$result['title'].'</span>
                            <span style="display: block;">'.$result['content'].'</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {    
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '|'), array(' ',' ', '&#124;'), '<span class="title">'.$result['title'].'</span><p>'.$result['content'].'</p>')
                .'|'
                .str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '|'), array(' ',' ', '&#124;'), $result['url'])
                ."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem with wordpress, it's worth asking your question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Its more of a php problem, changing php code to handle taxonomies instead of title. I did ask over there too but no help.